# Symfony2 - Doctrine - Old tables beeing created on schema:update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using symfony2 and doctrine and today using command

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

encountered the following error:

> [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]   Class
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Linkksiazkaokladka' does not exist

eventhough I had no `Entity\Linkksiazkaokladka.php` file.

I have also noticed that:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

generates entities which are not available in `/entity/` directory.

Comment: You can also clear doctrine cache doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `Resource/Config/Doctrine` directory is clear.

It seems that Doctrine generates entities first of all based on data in this directory.

In my case clearing `Resource/Config/Doctrine` helped.